# Updating mulltiple field in odoo11

Tags: xml, odoo-11, qweb

I have been trying to update multiple fields with the same value but I can't seems to figure out a way to do it.

`<field name="credit_limit" readonly="1" attrs="{'invisible':[('check_credit','!=',True)]}"/>`

And I want to update the **custom_credit** which is on the same database res_partner. Is there any easy way that I can do it via xml.
My optimum solution would be hidden field that would be take value from above field and update database when the submit button is clicked.

The new field would be like this but it should take value from above **credit_limit**.

`<field name="custom_credit" readonly="1" type="hidden"/>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a easy way to update `readonly="1"` or `invisible="1"` field in odoo form, you have to add the property `force_save="1"` to do so. But to keep track of change in `check_credit` field, you must write an `@api.onchage('check_credit')` function and use that value to set `custom_credit` field. Other ways can be inheriting `create` or `write` function, use `compute` property on `custom_credit` field, or use `related` property.